# I am trying to consume web api with access token. The code is failing with error 404 - Reason Phrase : Not Found

Tags: c#, webapi

```
using ApiGateway.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

namespace ApiGateway.Services
{
    public class WtsAccessService : IWtsAccessService
    {
        HttpClient _httpClient;
        public WtsAccessService()
        {
            _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://paradigmwindows.wtsparadigm.com/paradigmwindows-prod/api/auth/wts");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        }

        public async Task<string> GetToken(string clientId, string clientSecret)
        {
            //var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "token");
            //request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            //    "Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}")));
            Dictionary<string, string> postData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            postData.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            postData.Add("client_id", clientId);
            postData.Add("client_secret", clientSecret);
            postData.Add("system_key", "zsnjv225F3QXzQ");
            FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

            var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("Token", content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            var authResponse = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthResponse>(responseStream);
            return authResponse.access_token;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the access token from a web api call and use that further for calling web api method. The GetAccessToken method makes that Post call to web api.

Comment: Seems like your endpoint does not exists, hence the 404 error. Check in the docs what is the correct endpoint to hit.